# Cordova and multi core plugins won't work together

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, plugins

I'm currently learning this and am trying to get more than one core plugin to work in my app, I've been coding manually then submitting it to phonegap to build and test. Now I've got cordova setup on windows 7, followed the instructions from adobe documentation.

Making more than one core plugin into a app which phonegap then builds for me does not work. The only code I've used is in adobe's phonegaps documentation on version 3.5. If you use one core plugin however it works. All the code that you require for this question is in their documentation.

Code: index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.min.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <script>

    </script>
</head>
<body>

<!--/////////////////////////////Home - API \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\-->

<div data-role="page" id="home">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>API</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li><a href="#accel" onclick="readyAccel();">Accelerometer</a></li>
            <li><a href="#gps" onclick="readyGPS();">GPS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#compass" onclick="readyCompass();">Compass</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h4>Joshua</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->

<!--/////////////////////////////Home - API - END \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\-->    

<!--/////////////////////////////Accel - API \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\-->

<div data-role="page" id="accel">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Accelerometer</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <script>

             // The watch id references the current `watchAcceleration`
            var AccelID = null;

            // Wait for device API libraries to load
            //
            function readyAccel() {
                document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReadyAccel, false);
            }
            // device APIs are available
            //
            function onDeviceReadyAccel() {
                startAccel();
            }

            // Start watching the acceleration
            //
            function startAccel() {

                // Update acceleration every .1 seconds
                var options = { frequency: 100 };

                AccelID = navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(onSuccess, onError, options);
            }

            // Stop watching the acceleration
            //
            function stopAccel() {
                if (AccelID) {
                    navigator.accelerometer.clearWatch(AccelID);
                    AccelID = null;
                }
            }

            // onSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current acceleration
            //
            function onSuccess(acceleration) {
                var element = document.getElementById('accelerometer');

                element.innerHTML = 'Acceleration X: ' + acceleration.x + '<br />' +
                                    'Acceleration Y: ' + acceleration.y + '<br />' +
                                    'Acceleration Z: ' + acceleration.z + '<br />' +
                                    'Timestamp: '      + acceleration.timestamp + '<br />';
            }

            // onError: Failed to get the acceleration
            //
            function onError() {
                alert('onError!');
            }
        if(!isset($element)) {
            alert('failed');
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="accelerometer">Waiting for accelerometer...</div>
        <button onclick="stopAccel();">Stop Watching</button>
</div>

<!--/////////////////////////////Accel - API - END \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\-->

<!--/////////////////////////////GPS - API \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\-->

<div data-role="page" id="gps">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>GPS</h1>
    </div>

    <script>

        // Wait for device API libraries to load
        //
        function readyGPS() {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReadyGeo, false);
        }

        var GeoID = null;

        // device APIs are available
        //
        function onDeviceReadyGeo() {
            // Get the most accurate position updates available on the
            // device.
            var options = { enableHighAccuracy: true };
            GeoID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);
        }

        // onSuccess Geolocation
        //
        function onSuccess(position) {
            var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
            element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '  + position.coords.latitude      + '<br />' +
                                'Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude     + '<br />' +
                                '<hr />'      + element.innerHTML;
        }

        // clear the watch that was started earlier
        //
        function clearGeo() {
            if (GeoID != null) {
                navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(GeoID);
                GeoID = null;
            }
        }

            // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
            //
            function onError(error) {
              alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
                    'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
            }


   ////////Default Script Start\\\\\\\\\\

//    // Wait for device API libraries to load
//    //
//    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
//
//    var watchID = null;
//
//    // device APIs are available
//    //
//    function onDeviceReady() {
//        // Get the most accurate position updates available on the
//        // device.
//        var options = { enableHighAccuracy: true };
//        watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);
//    }
//
//    // onSuccess Geolocation
//    //
//    function onSuccess(position) {
//        var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
//        element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '  + position.coords.latitude      + '<br />' +
//                            'Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude     + '<br />' +
//                            '<hr />'      + element.innerHTML;
//    }
//
//    // clear the watch that was started earlier
//    //
//    function clearWatch() {
//        if (watchID != null) {
//            navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchID);
//            watchID = null;
//        }
//    }
//
//        // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
//        //
//        function onError(error) {
//          alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
//                'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
//        }

    //////////Default Script End\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

    </script>

  </head>
  <body>

<!--
    <p id="geolocation">Watching geolocation...</p>
    <button onclick="clearGeo();">Clear Location</button>
-->

      <p id="geolocation">Watching geolocation...</p>
        <button onclick="clearWatch();">Clear Watch</button>

</div>    

<!--/////////////////////////////GPS - API - END \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\-->

<!--/////////////////////////////COMPASS - API \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\-->

<div data-role="page" id="compass">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Compass</h1>
    </div>

    <script>

        // The watch id references the current `watchHeading`
        var CompassID = null;

        // Wait for device API libraries to load
        //
        function readyCompass() {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReadyCompass, false);
        }
        // device APIs are available
        //
        function onDeviceReadyCompass() {
            startCompass();
        }

        // Start watching the compass
        //
        function startCompass() {

            // Update compass every .1 seconds
            var options = { frequency: 100 };

            CompassID = navigator.compass.watchHeading(onSuccess, onError, options);
        }

        // Stop watching the compass
        //
        function stopCompass() {
            if (CompassID) {
                navigator.compass.clearWatch(CompassID);
                CompassID = null;
            }
        }

        // onSuccess: Get the current heading
        //
        function onSuccess(heading) {
            var element = document.getElementById('heading');
            element.innerHTML = 'Heading: ' + heading.magneticHeading;
        }

        // onError: Failed to get the heading
        //
        function onError(compassError) {
            alert('Compass error: ' + compassError.code);
        }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="heading">Waiting for heading...</div>
    <button onclick="stopCompass();">Stop Compass</button>

</div>    
<!--/////////////////////////////COMPASS - API - END \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\-->

</body>
</html>
```

Code: config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
    <preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTop" />
    <feature name="App">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.App" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Accelerometer">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.devicemotion.AccelListener" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Compass">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.deviceorientation.CompassListener" />
    </feature>
    <name>App Multi</name>
    <description>
        "Multi plugins"
    </description>
    <author email="email@address.com" href="http://google.com">
        Joshua
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
</widget>
```

I've changed the watchID's to see if it was in conflict with other plugins however this did not work.

Link to JS of API's:-

- Accelerometer : https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device-motion/blob/master/doc/index.md
- GPS : https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation/blob/master/doc/index.md

I cannot post more than two links so I think you can find the compass pretty easily from phonegaps documentation.

Comment: This is very vague for anyone to offer help with. Could you please add specific information such as which plugins you are trying to use, which platforms you are building for and include some of your JS for the plugins that you are seeing issues with. Thank you

Comment: Anyone? Anyone at all?

Comment: So, cordova isn't capable of utilizing multiple plugins? I searched tirelessly and found nothing but single plugin solutions.